# Error Twitter. Max retries exceeded (Correct keys used)

Tags: python-2.7, https, twitter-oauth, tweepy

I'm using tweepy and trying to run the basic script as shown by this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pUUxmvvl2FE).  I was previously receiving 401 errors (unsynchronized time zones) but am using the provided keys. I fixed that problem and now I'm getting this result:

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "algotest.py", line 25, in <module>
        twitterStream.filter(track=["North"])
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tweepy-2.3-py2.7.egg/tweepy/streaming.py", line 313, in filter
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tweepy-2.3-py2.7.egg/tweepy/streaming.py", line 235, in _start
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tweepy-2.3-py2.7.egg/tweepy/streaming.py", line 151, in _run
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests-2.2.1-py2.7.egg/requests/sessions.py", line 335, in request
        resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests-2.2.1-py2.7.egg/requests/sessions.py", line 438, in send
        r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests-2.2.1-py2.7.egg/requests/adapters.py", line 327, in send
        raise ConnectionError(e)
    requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='stream.twitter.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /1.1/statuses/filter.json?track=North&delimited=length (Caused by <class 'socket.gaierror'>: [Errno -2] Name or service not known)
```

Any way around this? Is there some sort of reset option I can trigger?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Turns out the solution is simply to wait a day. Who would've thought!

Answer (score 0):

I was also getting same error while using the python-twitter module in my script but it got resolved automatically when I tried after an interval. As there is limit for the number of try at a particular interval hence we get this error when we exceed that maximum try limit.